# Send email when a new row is inserted in exact target

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-alert

My requirement is to trigger an email to one Email Id whenever a new record/ROW is inserted in the DE.

Data will be in a standard DE.

Thanks,
Susmitha

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this depending on how the data is added to the DE. A standard triggered send will most likely work, how will the record be added to the DE?

Reference: [SOAP API: How to Send an Email Using a TriggeredSend Object](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/send-triggeredsend-email.html)

Answer (score 0):

Write a Workflow which will, wit "On Create" condition. And in actions Send an Email to the desired Email Address.

Comment: Shankish, may be you are refering to Salesforce Workflows. I would like to create in Exact target. I dont know/see an option to create with "On Create" condition.

Comment: Navigate to Workflow from setup. Create workflow for the desired object and there you should be able to see when you want to fire the workflow.

Comment: http://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/IqZIFLtEx9rY7AD8QLFE3Q

Comment: Thanks for ur response Shankish. But, we are not referring to SFDC, we are referring to Marketing cloud (Exact target)